# How to force covariance when resolving function overload?

Tags: c#, oop, overloading, covariance

In C# I can do this:

```
    public class BaseClass { };
    
    public class A : BaseClass
    {
        public void Foo(){ Console.WriteLine("A"); }
    };
    
    public class B : BaseClass
    {
        public void Bar(){ Console.WriteLine("B"); }
    };
    
    
    public static void SwitchThingy(BaseClass obj){
        Console.WriteLine("Default case");
    }
    
    public static void SwitchThingy(A obj){
        obj.Foo();
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        SwitchThingy(a);
        SwitchThingy(b);
    }
```

It will output

```
A
Default case
```

However, if I change Main() to

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        List<BaseClass> myList = new List<BaseClass>();
        myList.Add(a);
        myList.Add(b);

        SwitchThingy(myList[0]);
        SwitchThingy(myList[0]);
    }
```

Then output changes to

```
Default case
Default case
```

Which makes sense since no conversion is required for that overload and so it is preferred over the other which does require extra work.

How can I force the overload for the derived class to be called instead, like in the first case, but after putting the objects into a List?

All I want to avoid here is to have several subclasses (A, B, ...) implementing boilerplate code if possible as well as keep the implementation of `SwitchThingy` outside of the classes.

Comment: Why is it "besides the point" that you have shown exactly how to solve your problem via what is *by your own admission* a better choice?  You know the solution.  Use that solution.  If you have a problem that you *don't* have a solution for, *then* you ask a quesiton.

Comment: @Servy because the problem I'm trying to solve is more complex than this. Print is used as an easy to understand function example and again, has absolutely nothing to do with my question. It is not the problem I'm trying to solve. It is unrelated.

Comment: Shall the SwitchThingy implementations be all at the same place or spread over the code?

Comment: @Eric If this isn't the problem you're trying to solve then *describe the actual problem you're trying to solve*.  This problem is solved via a virtual method.  It's literally the exact reason the feature exists in the language to solve.  If you have a *different* problem then describe it, and people can provide the best solution to that other problem.

Comment: @NineBerry I guess that the ideal solution would be having all of them at the same place? If you have a solution that works for either case, I'm open to suggestions

Comment: @Servy I don't understand why you're so focused on a solution that has nothing to do with my question. Unless it is your goto answer to every question regarding covariant function overloading. This is a feature in C# and I'd like to know how it works. It's possible that virtual functions were developed to manage an edge case of this, but I really doubt so.

Comment: @Eric How does it have nothing to do with your question?  It solves the problem you're trying to solve, and by your own assertion, better than any alternatives.  This question has nothing to do with covariance.  You're just using the wrong term for the feature you want, which is literally virtual dispatch.  The `virtual` keyword is named after the exact concept of virtual dispatch which is exactly what you're asking for.  It's not a niche case, this is the *textbook* case for why virtual functions exist.  This is *the* reason they were created.

Comment: @Servy Virtual dispatch is another topic, unrelated to method overloading. It does solve the problem you're trying to solve, which is unfortunately not related to my question. You probably should read on covariance though, you don't seem to understand what it means, although it is probable that you still haven't figured out what my question is. Here's an helpful page from msdn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance. I know about virtual functions. What I don't know is how to force the runtime to select the type I want during method overloading

Comment: Method overload is chosen at compile time, so you can't "force runtime" to do that. By the way, generic covariance is completely unrelated to all this, if you carefully read the docs you linked.

Comment: @Evk well apparently I can cast my argument to dynamic and it will work. I realize that this keyword is not ideal, but I'm checking further material regarding the double dispatch problem. You're right that the link is not my exact problem, but it's the same set of challenges applied to generics instead of method parameter types

Comment: The problem you actually described if fundamentally polymorphism.  It has nothing to do with covariance at all.  (and your comments about covariance suggest you should really read up more on it because you seem to not understand what it is).  The best way to solve it is with a virtual method.  Using static methods is making things much, much harder on yourself and results in more complex, error prone and harder to maintain code.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you put the objects in a list of the base class type, the compiler will not any longer be able to help you. Decisions based on the actual type will then have to be made explicitly at runtime in your code.

---

One possible and classic approach to solve your problem is using the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

This way you only have to implement one "Accept" method in each of your classes. You can then create concrete Visitor classes to decide how to handle the different classes.

```
class Program
{

    public class BaseClass
    {
        public virtual void Accept(IBaseClassVisitor v)
        {
            v.Visit(this);
        }
    };


    public class A : BaseClass
    {
        public void Foo() { Console.WriteLine("A"); }
        public override void Accept(IBaseClassVisitor v)
        {
            v.Visit(this);
        }
    };

    public class B : BaseClass
    {
        public void Bar() { Console.WriteLine("B"); }
        public override void Accept(IBaseClassVisitor v)
        {
            v.Visit(this);
        }
    };

    public class C : BaseClass
    {
        public override void Accept(IBaseClassVisitor v)
        {
            v.Visit(this);
        }
    };

    public interface IBaseClassVisitor
    {
        void Visit(BaseClass obj);
        void Visit(A obj);
        void Visit(B obj);
        void Visit(C obj);
    }


    public class SwitchThingyVisitor : IBaseClassVisitor
    {
        public void Visit(BaseClass obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Default case");
        }

        public void Visit(A obj)
        {
            obj.Foo();
        }

        public void Visit(B obj)
        {
            obj.Bar();
        }
        public void Visit(C obj)
        {
            // refer to default implementation
            Visit((BaseClass)obj);
        }
    }


    public static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();

        List<BaseClass> myList = new List<BaseClass>();
        myList.Add(a);
        myList.Add(b);
        myList.Add(c);

        SwitchThingyVisitor visitor = new SwitchThingyVisitor();

        foreach (var obj in myList)
        {
            obj.Accept(visitor);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

---

A much simpler approach is having a routing function that does an explicit runtime check of the types and calls the respective functions. Newer c# versions allow using a concise syntax by using pattern matching:

```
class Program
{

    public class BaseClass
    {
    };

    public class A : BaseClass
    {
        public void Foo() { Console.WriteLine("A"); }
    };

    public class B : BaseClass
    {
        public void Bar() { Console.WriteLine("B"); }
    };

    public class C : BaseClass
    {
    };


    public static void RouteSwitchThingy(BaseClass obj)
    {
        switch (obj)
        {
            case A a:
                SwitchThingy(a);
                break;
            case B b:
                SwitchThingy(b);
                break;
            default:
                SwitchThingy(obj);
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void SwitchThingy(BaseClass obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Default case");
    }

    public static void SwitchThingy(A obj)
    {
        obj.Foo();
    }
    public static void SwitchThingy(B obj)
    {
        obj.Bar();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();

        List<BaseClass> myList = new List<BaseClass>();
        myList.Add(a);
        myList.Add(b);
        myList.Add(c);

        foreach (var obj in myList)
        {
            RouteSwitchThingy(obj);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The pattern matching solution is neat. I considered the visitor pattern initially, but my default case is in fact "do nothing" and I felt that I was writing a large amount of code to have absolutely no effect in the end. I'll wait a few days to see if anything else comes up (probably not) then Ill accept your solution